# Find intersection angle of curves : $y=x^3-5, y=5x^2-x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

[image: Work so far]

My work so far looks as above. Calculated angle seems too large?

Not sure what's wrong in here with my calculations. Thanks!

Comment: Almost all your work is correct. You have correctly found that the curves intersect at $x=5$ and you have correctly found the gradients. But they translate into angles of $89.24^o$ and $88.83^o$, so the angle between them is $0.405^o$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3-5=5x^2-x$$
$$x^3-5x^2+x-5=0$$
$$x=5$$
$$m_1=y_1'(5)=3(5)^2=75$$
$$m_2=y_2'(5)=10(5)-1=49$$
$$\phi=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{75-49}{1+75\times 49}\right)$$